# JavaのFiles.existsであるはずのファイルが確認できない

Tags: java, linux

java : jdk9.01
os : linux Red Hat 4.8.5-11

Javaのコードで他のプログラムの出力するファイルのチェックを数秒毎にチェックし、
存在を確認できたら次に進むというコードを書こうとしています。

```
int n = 0;
boolean flag = false;
while (flag == false) {
    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(waitsec);
    flag = Files.exists(path);
     n += 1;
     if (n > limit) {
         System.out.println("limit over");
     }
}
```

上のような感じで書いているのですが
ところがファイルが出力されているはずなのにflagがtrueになりません。
trueが帰ることもあるのですがタイミングがバラバラだったりします。
lsコマンドなどで自分で存在を確認すると
そのとたんにFiles.existsでもtrueが帰ります。

理由は分かりませんが、シュレディンガーの猫のような感じです。
自分で見つけた解決策としてはFiles.findを使えばなんとかなるのですが
Files.existsがなぜうまく作用しないのか理由がしりたいと考えています。

原因がわかる方がいましたら、ご教授お願いします。

Comment: 原因については分かりませんが、他のプログラムが作成するファイルの存在をチェックするのでしたら、Java7 から導入された WatchService を利用してみてはどうでしょうか。[File system events with Java 7](https://markusjais.com/file-system-events-with-java-7/)

Comment: 本題と関係ないかも知れないですが、環境条件に記載の「Red Hat 4.8.5-11」は誤記でしょうか? (Java9が動作する環境にしてはバージョンが古すぎるように見えるため)

Comment: WatchServiceを試してみたのですが、

Comment: なぜか自分の監視したいファイル出力は反応してくれませんでした・・・。
LinuxのVer.については誤記ではありません。自分もあまりハードに詳しくないためよく知らないのですが、LinuxのVer.が古いとよくないということですかね、OSのVer.は自分ではどうにもならないのでJavaのVer.を下げた方がいいかもないですね

Comment: WatchServiceが監視できるのはあくまで自身のPCが書き込んだイベントのみのようです。自分のケースの場合、ネットワークドライブ上の他のPCから出力されたファイルの監視だったのでWatchServiceは使えないようです。

Comment: @pikopiko なるほど、「ネットワークドライブ上の他のPCから出力されたファイルの監視」という事なのですね。その場合は [The inotify-java Open Source Project on Open Hub](https://www.openhub.net/p/inotify-java) の方が良いかもしれません。自分の経験では、NFS マウントした領域でもイベントを拾う事ができました。ただ、Linux OS の inotification を利用していますので、Linux システムでしか利用できませんが。。。

Answer (score 3):

ファイル出力側のプログラムでファイル出力をフラッシュしてない場合、タイミングよっては出力がバッファリングされた状態となり、ディスクに書き込まれてないので、他のプログラムからは読めないのかもしれません。

Cだとfflushやfsyncなどを使って明示的に書き込みをフラッシュしてみると変化があるかもしれません。また、Javaだと、PrintWriterなどのFlushableインターフェースの実装で flush() を呼び出すと書き込みがフラッシュされると思います。

Answer (score 2):

> ネットワークドライブ上の他のPCから出力されたファイルの監視

という条件から推測すると、NFS領域を非同期モードで使用しているため、他のPCで書き出した(作成した)ファイルが同期的に見えないため、と考えます。

NFSサーバのエクスポートオプションに「`sync`」を指定する、加えてNFSクライアントのマウントオプションにも「`sync`」を指定することで解消すると思います。

---

なお、OSは「RHEL4」ということですが、[Java9の動作条件](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/jdk9certconfig-3761018.html)によると、RHEL6以上とのことですので、Java9は見送られたほうがよいかと思います。

また、RHEL4のkernelは2.6.9ですので、inotify-java APIも動作しないかと思います。([inotify-javaのサイト](https://www.openhub.net/p/inotify-java)には、2.6.13以降が必要、とあるため)